# Equation numbers inside multiline vertical braces

Tags: align, numbering, amsmath, split

I have a sum expression with many terms. I would like to split the summands into two groups in order to be able to talk about the differences between group 1 terms and group 2 terms in general. I would also like to assign numbers to individual terms in order to be able to refer to them later. Thus I want to render the equation like this:

```
(1.1)    f_1(...)  }
                   }  group 1
(1.2)  + f_2(...)  }

(1.3)  + g_1(...)  }
                   }  group 2
(1.4)  + g_2(...)  }
```

(of course, there should be two large curly braces instead of many small ones)

How can one achieve this? I can get line numbers with `align` and I can get the braces with nested `split`s, but how does one get both?

Comment: I assume you are using a setup where equation numbers are on the left (`leqno`), right?

Comment: @KersouMan, that's definitely a step in the right direction, thanks! But how can I have two braces in one equation? If I use two `empheq` environments then terms from different groups are no longer aligned with each other.

Comment: @campa yes, I always have equation numbers are on the left in my setup

Comment: Please, make the example more understandable.

Comment: @egreg could you please elaborate? which part is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tricky solution using `bigdelim` package and `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
%\usepackage{hyperref} %optionnal

\newcommand\mydelim[2][0.5]{%
&\quad \rdelim\}{2}{3mm}&&\smash{\raisebox{-#1\baselineskip}[0pt]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{wholeset}
\begin{alignat}{3}
f_b(x)&=1+2+3 &  \mydelim{group one}\\
      &=f_1(\cdots)   \label{secondInGroupOne}\\
      &+ f_2(\cdots) &  \mydelim{grouptwo} \label{firstInGroupTwo}\\
      &+ f_3(\cdots)
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

The whole equation set \eqref{wholeset}.\par
The second line   \eqref{secondInGroupOne}.\par
The third line \eqref{firstInGroupTwo}.

\end{document}
```

where optional parameter `#1` of `\mydelim` is the number of `\baselineskip` required to properly space the right text (0.5 by default)
Direct hyperreference to a group would be more involved, but `(\ref{wholeset}a,b)`  should work.

[image]

**Edit:** if the number of lines to span is not constant to 2, you could add another optional parameter. Assuming `latex3` is enabled (or `xparse` loaded), you could replace `\newcommand\mydelim[2][0.5]{...}`
by:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mydelim}{D(){2}O{0.5}m}{%
&\quad \rdelim\}{#1}{3mm}&&\smash{\raisebox{-#2\baselineskip}[0pt]{#3}}%
}
```

that would be used as

`\mydelim(`*number of lines*`)[`*number of lineskips*`]{`*text*`}`

where the two first arguments are optional (default to 2 and 0.5 respectively)